# Memory being used by JVM when @Cacheable is used in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am using @Cacheable with SpringBoot where spring-boot-starter provides a default simple cache provider which stores values in an instance of ConcurrentHashMap. This is the simplest possible thread-safe implementation of the caching mechanism.

But when the load is increased in the cache, then which memory in JVM is being targeted for the load. Is it heap memory or local memory is being used.

Since on increasing the load to more than assigned load of the jar, I am not experiencing any Heap Memory Out of Memory issues.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by local memory ! Simple cache uses heap.

Comment: Local memory or you can say code cache in non-heap memory. Thanks @vmaroli

Comment: Not sure why my application is not throwing heap memory error even if the size of cache has been increased to 200 MB and my application maximum size is just 128 MB.